# Null check condition in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The match search is being made for 2 fields below, but if `ownerIdNo` is null, I don't want that search to be made for it.

```
{
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "idNo": "3504"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "ownerIdNo": "null"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Pseudo code like:

```
matchSearchFor(idNo);
if(ownerIdNo != null){
  matchSearchFor(ownerIdNo);
}
```

Comment: What programming language are you using to issue your queries?

Comment: I use C# and Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add if else in elastic - DSL it is not a procedural language.

You want to select documents where (ownerIdNo is null OR idNo": "3504"). In elasticsearch you have to use a should clause(OR).

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "idNo": "3504"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [ --> null fields are not stored in documents
              {
                "match": {
                  "ownerIdNo": "null"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, what I want is that if the ownerID is null, its match query should not be applied unnecessarily.

Comment: @OnurKayabaşı elasticsearch search creates an inverted index which stores which document have what terms. It will pick all the documents where field is not present , if present it will select passed id. So many query will not be applied if ownerid is not present

Comment: Yeah, I got it.Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Please accept as answer if it resolved your query. So that it may be helpful to others. Please note there is no obligation to do so